# Is is possible to dump the contents of a JCL SYSOUT to a z/OS flat file?

Tags: zos, jcl

I'm interested in knowing if it is possible to get the contents of a JCL SYSOUT into a z/OS flat file; either in the same JCL step or in a JCL step executed later in the same JCL.

Attention¡, I do not mean the other way round; which is generate the SYSOUT directy in a z/OS file and, after, in another JCL step dump it onto SYSOUT.

For example; in the following JCL step I'm interested in getting the contents of SYSOUT=2 in a flat file.

May anyone shed light in this issue?.

Many thanks in advance.

```
//WNMPRAD5 EXEC PGM=WNMPRAD5,COND=(4,LT)                     
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=1                                       
//SYSDBOUT DD SYSOUT=1                                       
//ENTRADA  DD DSN=WNMT.SCADUC.WGPT022.ZXDALMA.UNLDBI,DISP=OLD
//SORTIDA  DD DSN=WNMT.SCADUC.WGPT022.ZXDALMA.OUTPUT.V02,    
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),UNIT=DISK,             
//            DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=278),                      
//            SPACE=(27998,(2500,2500),RLSE)                 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=2                                       
//SYSIN    DD *                                              
N0100                                                        
/*
```

Comment: Do you want it to end up in two places (ie, both DD SYSOUT and in a flat file) or just in the flat file?

Comment: I'd like to get the program output in two places; both DD SYSOUT AND in the flat file; the answers I've received until now does not solve my issue since they first ask me to write the output of the program to a flat file and get the SYSOUT in a later step; in fact I do already know to do this. What I'm asking is the possibility of the other way round; keep DD SYSOUT=2 in the program step and, in a later step dump the contents of this SYSOUT to a flat file. Regards

Comment: So far, the answer appears to be no, at least, without writing a non-trivial amount of REXX.  Basically, you need to be able to refer back to the output of an earlier step in a later step, but the refer back documentation says specifically that you can't refer back to a DD SYSOUT= statement.

Answer (score 3):

`SYSOUT` is no different than any other DD but is used by convention for output.  You can create a DD like this in the STEP that creates the file:

```
//SYSOUT   DD DSN=MY.SYSOUT,    
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),UNIT=DISK,             
//            DCB=(RECFM=FBA,LRECL=133,BLKSIZE=0),                      
//            SPACE=(27998,(2500,2500),RLSE)
```

The DCB will vary depending but 133 (assuming ASA character) is common.  No need for a different step.

If you want, you could in a following step use IEBGENER to copy the Disk to another SYSOUT to store the contents in the JOB.  Its not possible, as far as I know, to easily grab a SYSOUT in the next step and copy to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You have to get the LRECL and RECFM correct, but you can get those from the source code to the program you're executing.  Most standard reports are 133 and FB or 132 and FBA.  I seem to remember IDCAMS was 121 and VBA.

```
//WNMPRAD5 EXEC PGM=WNMPRAD5,COND=(4,LT)                     
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=1                                       
//SYSDBOUT DD SYSOUT=1                                       
//ENTRADA  DD DSN=WNMT.SCADUC.WGPT022.ZXDALMA.UNLDBI,DISP=OLD
//SORTIDA  DD DSN=WNMT.SCADUC.WGPT022.ZXDALMA.OUTPUT.V02,    
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),UNIT=DISK,             
//            DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=278),                      
//            SPACE=(27998,(2500,2500),RLSE) 
//SYSOUT   DD  DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
//             DSN=&SYSUID..STEPNAME.SYSOUT,
//             AVGREC=K,
//             LRECL=133,
//             RECFM=FB,
//             SPACE=(500,(10,10))
//SYSIN    DD *                                              
N0100                                                        
/*
```

Answer (score 2):

Provide the disposition parameter and dataset name in the sysout. So, it will be something like

//sysout dd dsn=abc.xyz,disp=(as per your choice)